# A method that prints out a number of asteriskw for the number given

Tags: java

I was wondering what would the coding be if I wanted to make a code which prints out a number of asterisk for the value I give.

For example, If i input the values values: {3, 2, 1}
I would get

---

**
*

```
public void stars(int[] values)
```

, this is the beginning of my code

Comment: Do you mean for a value 5, you get `*****`?

Comment: you mean ***** for 5 or * which has 5 edges?

Comment: Hi I edited the question for a better understanding, please look :)

Comment: If you input `{3, 2, 1}` you get `** *`? So the first number indicates the total number of `*`?

Comment: You are keeping us interested :) Can you tell us what edited question means?

Comment: I am glad you showed us the beginning of your code, now we know you really tried to solve this yourself /sarcasm

Comment: No as in I was referring to the error I get in a code I used

So when I type in {1,2,3} in an array
I expect to get
*
**
*** returned

So i get a number of asterisks corresponding with the values I input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats it:

```
public void print(int input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
       System.out.print("*");
    }
}
```

**EDIT by comment:**

```
public static void print(int[] input) {
    for (int inp : input) {
        for (int i = 0; i < inp; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    print(new int[]{2, 5});
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
** *****
```

Comment: Hi thanks so much for your response!! It was really helpful , unfortunately I forgot to mention it was an array function

So i started it off as
public void stars(int[] values)

I inputted your code using {2,3}
expecting it to return a
**
***

except I just got **, any pointers?

Comment: @JudyTran You should put that in you question.

Comment: Here you go :) Edited the answer, take a look.

Answer (score 2):

```
    int count = 5;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i<count;i++)
    {
        builder.append("*");
    }
    System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Assuming you wanted number of `*` to be equal to count.

**Update:**
I guess you can build your solution on top of above solution. I guess you should give it a try.

Comment: You could also do while (builder.length() < count) {...}, but what ever works ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, dirty one-line hack:

```
public String repeatAsterisk(int number) {
    return new String(new char[number]).replaceAll(".", "*");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To pad out characters with asterisk(*) using `Arrays.fill()`:

```
public static void stars(int[] values) {
    for (int value: values) {
        char[] numberChars = new char[value];
        Arrays.fill(numberChars, '*');
        System.out.print(numberChars);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for   
 1 = *           
 5 = *****
```

int count = 5;

```
         for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String numToAsterisk(int num) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(num);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
       sb.append("*");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

or do you want this?

```
public void stars(int[] values) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int val : values) {
        for (int i = 0; i < val; ++i) {
            sb.append("*");
        }
        sb.append(" ");
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString().trim());
}
```

Output for `stars(new int[]{2, 4, 5});` will be `** **** *****`.